# Валидация в форме с помощью правила compare в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Столкнулся с проблемой. При валидации формы, созданной с помощью ActiveForm в виде, не работает правило валидации 'compare' - атрибут всегда выдает ошибку.

Правила валидации в модели:

```
public function rules(): array
{
   return [
      [['oldPassword', 'newPassword', 'confirmNewPassword'], 'trim'],
      ['oldPassword', 'required', 'message' => 'Введите старый пароль'],
      ['oldPassword', 'validatePassword'],
      ['newPassword', 'required', 'message' => 'Придумайте пароль'],
      ['newPassword', 'string', 'length' => [5, 30], 'tooLong' => 'Максимум 30 символов', 'tooShort' => 'Минимум 5 символов'],
      ['newPassword', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[\w-]+$/i', 'message' => 'Используются недопустимые символы'],
      ['confirmNewPassword', 'required', 'message' => 'Подтвердите Ваш пароль'],
      ['confirmNewPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'newPassword', 'type' => 'string' ,'message' => 'Пароли не совпадают'],
  ];
}
```

Фрагмент кода из вида:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'changePasswordForm',
    'action' => Url::to('/user/change-password'),
]) ?>
<?= $form
    ->field($model, 'oldPassword')
    ->input('password', [
        'id' => 'oldPasswordInput',
        'class' => 'txt-input-basic',
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'placeholder' => 'Старый пароль',
    ])
    ->label(false) ?>
<?= $form
    ->field($model, 'newPassword')
    ->input('password', [
        'id' => 'newPasswordInput',
        'class' => 'txt-input-basic',
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'placeholder' => 'Новый пароль',
    ])
    ->label(false) ?>
<?= $form
    ->field($model, 'confirmNewPassword')
    ->input('password', [
        'id' => 'confirmNewPasswordInput',
        'class' => 'txt-input-basic',
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'placeholder' => 'Подтвердите новый пароль',
    ])
    ->label(false) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Вопрос именно во встроенной **клиентской** валидации, так как валидация на сервере (в том числе через свою ajax функцию) работает.

Comment: Можете показать текст ошибки

Comment: @Евгений там именно ошибка валидации, то есть с точки зрения работы кода - ошибок нет, но валидатор Yii не валидирует на стороне клиента. Исходя из приложенного кода к вопросу мы заполняем два поля (с атрибутами `newPassword` и `confirmNewPassword`). Мы не отправляем форму и видим ошибку, что поля не совпадают, но если отправить форму, то на сервере все валидируется и данные обновляются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сложно сказать - баг это или фича. Но проблема исчезает, если у сравниваемого атрибута убрать из параметров ID.
То есть если следующее поле будет выглядеть так:

```
<?= $form
    ->field($model, 'newPassword')
    ->input('password', [
        'class' => 'txt-input-basic',
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'placeholder' => 'Новый пароль',
    ])
    ->label(false) ?>
```